# regular validation expression in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, regex

i have got a code to edit some function. There is a text box in that web application. It using a regular expression validator control to validate the text box. the validation expression is

ValidationExpression="[\w]{3,15}"

it accept all letters,numbers and underscores. but it do not accept special characters like \,/ * . i want to change the above regular expression to accept / .

i hope someone can explain what the above regular expression means and how to change that expression to accept / without affecting current regular expression
i am using asp.net and c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You current regular expression can be deconstructed as follows :

[] brackets represents regular expression group. Regex engine will try to match all the characters or group of characters given inside [] with the input string.

\w - Allow all the alpha numberic characters which includes upper case and lower case alphabets and 0 to 9 numbers and and underscore (This does not include other special characters like / or # ,etc ).

{3,15} means minimum 3 and maximum 15 alphanumeric characters must be provided in order to successfully match the string.

To add other charters, you need to add them explicitly. If you want to add / your regex should be like [\w/]{3,15}.

You can learn everything about regex [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Comment: thank you. one more doubt. if i want to check the size only , what can i do. i tried like this -> ValidationExpression="{3,15}"   .But its giving an error

Comment: got the answer. ValidationExpression=".{3,15}"   . thank u again

Comment: Size of what? input text? If you want to check size / length of input text, then you can just string.length method.

Comment: alryt. but i wanted it to do from client side. problem is fixed. thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
string ValidationExpression= "[\w/]{3,15}"
```

- `[...]` match a single character presents in the list between brackets
- `[...]{3,15}` match between 3 and 15 characters presents between brackets
- `\w` match a word character (letter, digit, underscore...)
- `/` match the character `/`

So `[\w/]{3,15}` match a word character or '/' between 3 and 15 times.

Comment: I think there is no need to give pipe (|) symbol in [] brackets.

Comment: @Shekhar, you're totally right. i've updated my answer. Thanks